# from PyQt4.QtGui: NameError: name 'QtGui' is not defined

Tags: python, qt4

I have followed the specific kind of import rather than writing *.
`from PyQt4.QtGui`

What else am I missing?

```
import sys

from PyQt4.QtGui import QMainWindow, QSizePolicy, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QAction,\
        QKeySequence, QLabel, QItemSelectionModel, QMessageBox, QFileDialog, QFrame, \
        QDockWidget, QProgressBar, QProgressDialog

from PyQt4.QtCore import SIGNAL, QSettings, QSize, QPoint, QVariant, QFileInfo, QTimer, pyqtSignal, QObject


class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QGraphicsView.__init__(self, parent)
        self.scene = QtGui.QGraphicsScene(self)
        self.scene.setBackgroundBrush(QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.darkGray, QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern))
        self.setScene(self.scene)

        self.setDragMode(QtGui.QGraphicsView.ScrollHandDrag)
        self.setTransformationAnchor(QtGui.QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)
        self.viewport().setCursor(QtCore.Qt.CrossCursor)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)

        self._pan = False
        self._draw = False
        self._moved = False
        self._sel = False
        self.pen = None
        self.penid = None
        self.cmap = None
        self.penwidth = 4
        self._redoStack = []
        self._histStates = []
        self._baseRects = [] 

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
GUI = Window()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: You imported it as `PyQt4.QtGui`.

Comment: So, what should be written instead? @Aran-Fey

Comment: The import is fine, but you have to use `PyQt4.QtGui` instead of just `QtGui` to reference it.

Comment: @Aran-Fey I tried  `class Window(PyQt4.QtGui.QMainWindow):`. It resulted in 
`NameError: name 'PyQt4' is not defined`

Comment: Oops, clearly I'm still half asleep... Yeah, I guess you have to add `from PyQt4 import QtGui`.

Comment: @Aran-Fey Now I tried this: `from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, QMainWindow, QSizePolicy, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QAction,\` This resulted in: 
`ImportError:cannot import name QMainWindow`

Comment: Just _add_ the line `from PyQt4 import QtGui` to your code and don't change anything else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the [following lines to the code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49608401/from-pyqt4-qtgui-nameerror-name-qtgui-is-not-defined?noredirect=1#comment86223630_49608401) and that solved the error:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QtCore
```

It looks like this now:

```
import sys

from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QtCore

from PyQt4.QtGui import QMainWindow, QSizePolicy, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QAction,\
        QKeySequence, QLabel, QItemSelectionModel, QMessageBox, QFileDialog, QFrame, \
        QDockWidget, QProgressBar, QProgressDialog

from PyQt4.QtCore import SIGNAL, QSettings, QSize, QPoint, QVariant, QFileInfo, QTimer, pyqtSignal, QObject
```